# Asp.Net MVC - Selecionar item de um DropDownList refletir a mesma seleção em outro DropDownList que contem os mesmo itens de seleção

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho 02 campos DropDownList que tem os mesmos itens para ser selecionado, isto é:

- Câmara 1
- Câmara 2
- Câmara 3
- Câmara 4
- Câmara 5
- Câmara 6

Resumindo em grande parte dos cadastros que será realizado, a seleção de um item do DropDownList Camara Lado A >> sendo ela qualquer uma mas exemplificando 
 o item **Câmara 4** o mesmo resultado de item selecionado deve refletir no DropDownList Câmara Lado B

Como fazer em Javascript para que Eu possa ter esta interação dos campo, pois assim evitarei do usuário selecionar a mesma coisa no DropDownList consecutivo.

**Câmara Lado A**

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CamaraLadoA, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CamaraLadoA", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CamaraLadoA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Câmara Lado B**

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CamaraLadoB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CamaraLadoB", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CamaraLadoB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o evento `change`, seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $("#CamaraA").change(function(){            
        $("#CamaraB").val(this.value)
    }) 
</script>
```

É capturado o evento `change`, após isso é atribuído o valor daquele item para o outro elemento.

Caso queira fazer o inverso(CamaraB alterar CamaraA), basta replicar o código com os `id` trocados

Deixei o código no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rmNURR) para referencia

Answer (score 1):

Cara, se eu entendi bem a pergunta eu já tive esse problema e usei select.selectedIndex com jquery e resolveu. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp